# FIND THE LAST REGISTER ON A TABLE SQL

Tags: sql, function, field

I have this:

Table **CLIENT**:

```
CLI_ID   STUDENT
   1     name1
   2     name2
   3     name3
```

Table **UNIVERSITY**:

```
UNIV_ID   CLI_ID    NAME
1...........1      harvard (2012)
2...........1      oxford(2013)
3...........2      yale
```

I need:

```
STUDENT    UNIVERSITY
name1      oxford
name2      yale
```

But I get:

```
STUDENT    UNIVERSITY
name2      yale
```

I'm only getting the highest number. not all students with the highst id (last University)

I alredy tried this:

```
**SELECT** C.cli_id, UNIV.UNIV_ID **FROM** cliente C

**INNER JOIN** UNIVERSITY UNIV **ON** C.Cli_id = UNIV.cli_id

**WHERE** UNIV_ID = ( **SELECT MAX** (UNIV_ID) **FROM** UNIVERSITY )
```

THANKS

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for here. Do you want to run a `SELECT... WHERE` and display the university associated to the last modified record?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of those `<br>` tags or dots (for spaces) either!

Comment: So what have you tried? What do you have trouble with? Which SQL dialect?

Comment: How do you determine `the last`?  Is it the maximum `ID` value for a student?

Comment: What I would like to find is the list of students with their last university. the last its the highst  ID ( in the example, oxford would be the las university for student 'name1' ).. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a correlated subquery in the `where` clause in order to get the max for each student:

```
SELECT C.cli_id, UNIV.UNIV_ID 
FROM cliente C INNER JOIN
     UNIVERSITY UNIV
     ON C.Cli_id = UNIV.cli_id
WHERE UNIV_ID = ( SELECT MAX(UNIV_ID) FROM UNIVERSITY u2 where u2.cli_id = c.cli_id)
```

You were getting the maximum over all the students and you only want the maximum for each student.